# C# MVC How to initialize ViewDataDictionary with both TemplateInfo and KeyValuePairs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dictionary, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

I can initialize a `ViewDataDictionary` with `Keys` and `Values` or a property called `TemplateInfo` but not both.

Either this works

```
Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/_myPartial1.cshtml", Model, new ViewDataDictionary
{
    TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo { HtmlFieldPrefix = "myForm_" }
});
```

or this works

```
Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/_myPartial1.cshtml", Model, new ViewDataDictionary
{
    { "ButtonText", "Hello!" }
});
```

But not both

```
Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/_myPartial1.cshtml", Model, new ViewDataDictionary
{
    TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo { HtmlFieldPrefix = "myForm_" },
    { "ButtonText", "Hello!" }
});
```

I get an error--- `"Invalid initializer member declarator"`

I'm guessing this could apply to other types of `Dictionary / KeyValuePair` sub- classes, so maybe the more general form of this question would be...

"Is there a short cut way of initializing a dictionary's subclass with its members and additional properties ?
If not then any easy alternatives ?"

We're still on .Net 4.5 at work so I may not have access to the latest improvements in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help you?

```
var dict = new ViewDataDictionary
{
    { "ButtonText", "Hello!" }
};
dict.TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo { HtmlFieldPrefix = "myForm_" };

Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/_myPartial1.cshtml", Model, dict);
```

Comment: Thanks! Its working. I was wondering if there was a one-line approach to it

Comment: You can create an extension method `public static ViewDataDictionary SetTemplateInfo(this ViewDataDictionary dict, TemplateInfo ti)` then init your object like this: `Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/_myPartial1.cshtml", Model, new ViewDataDictionary { { "ButtonText", "Hello!" } }.SetTemplateInfo(new TemplateInfo{ HtmlFieldPrefix = "myForm_" }));`